# In shopify set default product image size

Tags: shopify, image-size

In Shopify when we upload a product image for example one thats 1500px by 1500px it seems to resize the image to like 500 by 500 and we want all the images to be much bigger like we want them to be 700px by 700px.

Is there any default setting in the admin panel or is this all dependent on how the theme was coded and most likly something in the theme is scaling the image(s) down upload upload?

Comment: Think you have to play around with :
settings_schema.json and see if you can locate the setting to modify it there.

Comment: Thank you unfortunately I looked in the settings_schema.json  and the settings_data.json file and they don't have any reference to image sizing

Comment: You might try to locate the section responsible for displaying product images. It could be in various files depending on how the theme is structured, but common locations include product.liquid or sections/product-template.liquid.